# How I can execute many queries in one page?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I write this code but when I run it no output. There is no error but the problem no output.

How I can execute many queries in the same page?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> tran </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'uoh');
$query = "SELECT * FROM `student_record` id = 201102887;";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM `course` where id = 201102887;"; 

if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
do {
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo $row['code'];
echo $row['term'];
}
}   
} while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make an array of queries and foreach through them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: there is an error. You are missing a where in the first query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `student_record` id = 201102887;";
```

has to be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `student_record` where id = 201102887;";
```

That is sufficient to have a blank screen.

For the rest your code is ok, in line with the classical example from:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

What I wonder is if you really configured your server to execute php inside html.

Put this part of your code with the above correction in a .php file and you will see results:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'uoh');
$query = "SELECT * FROM `student_record` where id = 201102887;";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM `course` where id = 201102887;"; 

    if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
        do {
            if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo $row['code'];
                    echo $row['term'];
                }
            }   
        } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
    }
/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I added the missing where and the closure of the connection.

By the way, I hope you are sure the records with those ids exist in your DB.

Answer (score -1):

Just run your queries one by one using regular mysqli_query.

Leave multi_query alone, it is not for your case.